# CAPL decompiler from cbf to can

Tags: decompiling, decompiler, capl

I accidentally overridden a nice `*.can` CALP script I developed with a blank file, saved and have no backup, but lucky me, I still have the compiled version of it.

Is there a way to reverse engineering my way back to source code (`file.can`) from the binary file (`file.cbf`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is **NO**.
It is not possible to get back the `*.can` file from the binary output `*.cbf`.

Comment: Do you know why this is?

Comment: It is the same reason as with any compiling process. Once it goes through the compiler, it is not possible to go back. It is possible to forward though (compiled files can be converted into assembly code).
If you know about dlls' then this is similar to that. We do not know in what language those compiled files were written. It is just translated into code which is readable by machine.

Comment: put in another words: there is no open-sourced tool (so far) capable of decompiling the files, as of now. You can decompile dlls based on several assumptions regarding assembly code